# How concatenate gray and rgb channel of image using python

Tags: python, opencv

I have following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
gray = cv2.imread('b.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

print('a shape:', img.shape)  # a shape: (50,50,3)
print('b shape:', img.shape)  # b shape: (50,50)

result = np.concatenate((img, gray), axis=2)
print('result: ', result.shape)  # hope result shape: (50, 50, 4)
```

I get a exception as following :

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I want to get result.shape = (50, 50, 4), **4 channels**. How to revise my code?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are looking for [np.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
result = np.dstack((img, gray))
```